# How do I make an option selected in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

This is dropdown:

```
$cities = array('' => '-- All --');
$cities += CHtml::listData(Cities::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'city', $cities, array('class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'width:auto', 'onchange'=>'$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pay").trigger("click");});' ) );
```

I want to make the --All-- option to be selected by default. how can I do that ?

Update: I tried like this :

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'city', $cities,  array('options' => array(''=>array('selected'=>true))), array('class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'width:auto', 'onchange'=>'$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pay").trigger("click");});'));
```

but not working.
This is the html generated:

```
<select name="FitnessSubscriber[city]" id="FitnessSubscriber_city">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- All --</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Cluj-Napoca</option>
<option value="2">Baia Mare</option>
<option value="3">Iași</option>
<option value="5">Timisoara</option>
<option value="6">Bucuresti</option>
</select>
```

UPDATE MODEL:
This is the city model:

```
class Cities extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }


    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'cities';
    }


    public function rules()
    {

        return array(
            array('name', 'length', 'max'=>45),

            array('id, name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations()
    {

        return array(
            'city' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserLocations', 'city_id'),
            'locations' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Locations', 'city_id'),
            'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Users', 'location_id'),
                        'gyms'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FitnessGym', 'city_id'),
                        'pools'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SwimPool', 'city_id'),

        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        );
    }

    public function search()
    {

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ListData and ListOptions here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail

Comment: I love the yii documentation, a lot of theories, zero examples :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `"prompt"=> "---All---"` inside `$htmlOptions`:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'city', $cities, array('class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'width:auto', 'onchange'=>'$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pay").trigger("click");});', "prompt"=> "--All--" ) );
```

Also remove " --All-- " from data list if you've add it before. Because it's not a real data!

Comment: it still shows me the first city from $cities and does not display the string "--All--" in the dd

Comment: I tested and it worked for me. I have `<?php echo $form->dropDownList($profile, 'grade_id', CHtml::listData(Grade::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array("class" => 'selectpicker',"prompt"=>"choose")); ?>` in my projects and everything is right.

Comment: can you tell me where is declare grade_id in your case ?

Comment: Make sure spelling of the "prompt" is correct. Also make sure you put `"prompt"=>"--All--"` in the right position inside dropdown array. I'm sure your solution is `"prompt"=>"--All--"`.

Comment: `grade_id` is a foreign key from `Grade` table. Each `profile` has a `grade_id` field.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it still does not work :(

Comment: No problem, Can you post your two models? Cities and main model

Comment: for some reason it ignores the prompt and put it Cluj Napoca as option selected

Comment: Please add `city` relation in your User model.

Comment: thx for your help I really appreciate it and srry for your time, But my problem was in the view, there was an if condition which influenced my $model, Your answer was good from the beginning. Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way..

```html
echo $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Cities::find()->all(),'city_id', 'city_name'),
            ['prompt' => '--Select City--'],
            ['active' => $model->city], //Here you add the city you want to set selected
    );
```